# htcaccess - Use RewriteRule using slice of {HTTP_REFERER}

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am implementing the translation of a whole PHP site with GETTEXT. I've got a bunch of PHP files (one for each section), and I control the language via a GET variable:

```
http://www.domain.com/section.php?lang=en [for english]
```

My first goal is to put this in a nice and clean way, such as:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/section
```

I sort of managed to do that (not so nicely) via .htcaccess, but then I come up with two issues:

1. I'd like every page to identify the language used by taking a look at HTTP_REFERER (is that possible?), so I don't need to rely on SESSION and COOKIES, in case someone has them turned off. I guess the other option would be to echo the current language /en/ in front of every href...
2. How can I tell htcaccess to rewrite, at the same time:

This:

```
http://www.domain.com/XX/path/to/whatever/?var1=a&var2=b
```

To:

```
http://www.domain.com/path/to/whatever.php?lang=en&var1=a&var2=b
```

And this:

```
http://www.domain.com/XX/assets/js/functions.js
```

To:

```
http://www.domain.com/assets/js/functions.js?lang=en
```

Or in other words:

- If the path HAS a 2-char folder right after the domain name AND doesn't have an extension, remove the 2-char folder, append a .php to the end of the path, then ?lang=XX, and then the GET variables that came in. Maybe it could first check if it exists as a folder with its own index.php ??
- If the path HAS a 2-char folder right after the domain name AND HAS an extension, do the same thing, but keeping the original extension

I know that's a long question to ask, but I'm really lost here...I read a lot about it, but REGEX/htaccess are just too tough for me...I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Why do you want to look at the referrer if you can just look at the current url? Or do you want people coming in from a different site to be redirected to the page in their language? A better way for that would be to look at the Accept-Language header instead of referer.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For the no extension part I would just put `whatever.php` in a folder named `whatever`, and rename the php to `index.php`. Way easier than with htaccess